# Join SPQuery in list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column, spquery

List 1 "Posts", fields

```
 Title      body   #comments     modified
```

in this list #comments fields is look up from another list Comments:

List 2 "Comments", fields

```
title     body   comments      post tilte modified
```

in this list post "title" field is look up from list 1.

Now I have to form a join `SPQuery` to get a comments list modified field.

```
SPList listFaculty = web.Lists["Posts"];
            SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
            query.Query = "<where></where>";
            query.Joins = "<join Type='Left' ListAlias='Comments'>" + "<eq><fieldref Name='Title' RefType='ID' />" + "<fieldref List='Comments1' Name='ID' /></eq></join>";
            query.ProjectedFields = "<field Name='Modified1' Type='Lookup' List='Comments1' ShowField='Modified'/>"; 
            query.ViewFields = "<fieldref Name='Modified1' />";
            SPListItemCollection lists = listFaculty.GetItems(query);
```

I'm getting error

> Value does not fall within the range

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it work without the join/projectedfields?

Answer (score 0):

I am not a SharePoint developer but currently working with Sharepoint api so going through similar issues. I have seen these error few time and here's how I fixed it.

Firstly, not sure its just in this example or you actually have such filed names. I would suggest, if possible, update them to remove # and space. Field with space have different internal name which is what you should be using but in that you will get different error.

Let's say you have two List

```
Posts
Title   Body    CommentsLookup  Modified

Comments
Title   Body    Comment PostTitleLookup Modified
```

Your join query should be like

```
query.Joins = "<Join Type='LEFT' ListAlias='Comments'>" + "<Eq><FieldRef Name='CommentsLookup' RefType='Id' />" + "<FieldRef List='Comments' Name='ID' /></Eq></Join>";
query.ProjectedFields = "<Field Name='CommentModified' Type='Lookup' List='Comments' ShowField='Modified'/>"; 
query.ViewFields = "<Fieldref Name='CommentModified' />";
```

XML should look like

```
<View>
<Joins>
    <Join Type='LEFT' ListAlias='Comments'>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='CommentsLookup' RefType='Id'/>
            <FieldRef List='Comments' Name='ID'/>
        </Eq>
    </Join>
</Joins>
<ProjectedFields>
    <Field ShowField ='Modified' Type ='Lookup' Name ='CommentModified' List ='Comments'/>
</ProjectedFields>
<ViewFields>
    <FieldRef Name='CommentModified'/>
</ViewFields>
```

From my troubleshooting, that issue be caused by trying to project field that has same name in both lists (like Title).

Hope it help